# iOS app seems to register as Android device using Bluemix Push Cordova plugin

Tags: ibm-cloud, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am trying to run the sample for bluemix push cordova app from here:

I am able to install the sample on the iOS device and when I click the register button, getting the following response:

```
{"createdTime":"2016-08-23T10:53:26Z","lastUpdatedTime":"2016-08-23T10:53:26Z","createdMode":"API","deviceId":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx","userId":"anonymous","token":"xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx","platform":"A","href":"https://xxxxxx.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/xxxxxx/devices/xxxxxx"}
```

In the response I can see that

> "platform":"A"

which might be suggesting that the device is registering itself as Android device.

When i tried to push a test message to the app from Bluemix console to iOS devices, it says "No Devices Found". That not the case for Android. I am able to receive the push to Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'A' refers to an iOS device (tag being Apple) rather than a Google Android device ('G'). This can be seen on the REST API by selecting the 'Model' view rather than the 'Model Schema' view.

```
platform (string, optional):

The device platform. 'A' refers to Apple(iOS) devices and 'G' refers to Google(Android) devices. = ['A', 'G']
string
Enum:   "A", "G"
```

Regarding the failure to receive push notifications on iOS I would make certain that your APNs certificate is valid and properly configured. If a push is attempted by Bluemix and APNs responds that the device token is invalid due to a certificate issue then it is pruned from the device list to prevent further failed attempts which may be why you are seeing the 'No Devices Found' error.

If everything looks good with your certificate please let us know your Push Service GUID (found on the Mobile Options button in your Push Dashboard's configure page) so we can investigate further.